# Форматированный вывод в textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

Есть текст например

```
$short='Текст Текст Текст Текст <br>Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст ';
```

Выводится на страницу таким кодом

```
echo "\n<b>Краткая новость</b>: <textarea name=\"short\" rows=\"20\" cols=\"95\" value=\"\">$short</textarea><br><br>";
```

Суть проблемы в чем: весь текст выводится одной строкой, как мне отформатировать текст чтобы поле `<br>` в полн textarea был абзац, ниже приведу два скрина как есть, и как надо...

Заранее спасибо!

Как есть:

[image]

Как надо:

[image]

Comment: [NL2BR][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.su/functions/?nl2br

Comment: наоборот надо ;)

Comment: а ну да :) это первое что в голову пришло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте перед echo:

```
$short = str_replace('<br>', "<br>\n\n", $short);
```

Comment: Опередил =)))))